# XSL xsl:evaluate multiple nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

How can I make sure, that xsl:evaluate returns a sequence of nodes, in case the xPath matches multiple nodes.

Suppose the following input.xml

```
<numlist key="K1">
 <numlitm key="K2">C1</numlitm>
 <numlitm key="K2">C2</numlitm>
 <numlitm key="K3">C3</numlitm>                            
</numlist>
```

And the following XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xst="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                version="3.0">

    <xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var">//*[@key='K2']</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="eval">
            <xsl:evaluate xpath="$var" context-item="$main-doc" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$eval"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is

```
<numlitm key="K2">C1</numlitm>
<numlitm key="K2">C2</numlitm>
```

I would like the result, stored in `eval`, to be a sequence of two elements, so that I can iterate over the two `numlitm` via a for-each loop (I need this to construct a key). The issue is that the result seems not to be a node sequence, thus a for-each iteration will yield both numlitm rows, instead of each row in one seperate iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default type for a variable is a document-node. So, type your variable as a sequence of `element()`, or at least a sequence of `item()`.

```
<xsl:variable name="eval" as="element()*">
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="eval" as="item()*">
```

and then the `$eval` will be a sequence of the selected items from the evaluated XPath.

Comment: Those `as` declarations also ensure the variable "stores" the selected nodes from the used input document, without the `as` the document or document fragment formed contains copies of the nodes selected by the`xsl:evaluate`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a serial string for the same key.
→ Than you could try something like this:

```
<root>
 <xsl:for-each-group select="//numlitm" group-by="@key">
 <xsl:variable name="currentKey" select="@key"/>
 <SameKey>
  <!-- Serialize Nodestrings -->
  <xsl:variable name="nodestrings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//numlitm[@key=$currentKey]/text()" mode="serialize"/> <!-- get all tag-values for current group-key --> 
  </xsl:variable>
  <key><xsl:value-of select="$currentKey"/></key>
  <keyValues><xsl:value-of select="$nodestrings"/></keyValues>
 </SameKey>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
</root>
```

For this you will receive this output:

```
<root>
 <SameKey>
  <key>K2</key>
  <keyValues>C1C2</keyValues>
 </SameKey>
 <SameKey>
  <key>K3</key>
  <keyValues>C3</keyValues>
 </SameKey>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that the result seems not to be a node sequence, thus a for-each iteration will yield both numlitm rows, instead of each row in one seperate iteration

Your assumption is false. It is probably based on incorrect implementation of the `xsl:for-each` instruction - which your question neglects to show. If you do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>
 
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="var">//*[@key='K2']</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="eval">
        <xsl:evaluate xpath="$var" context-item="$main-doc" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="$eval/numlitm">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get the expected result of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item>C1</item>
   <item>C2</item>
</output>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiorv1f